# How to determine if string contains specific substring within the first X characters

Tags: c#

I want to check whether `Value1` below contains "abc" within the first X characters. How would you check this with an `if` statement?

```
var Value1 = "ddabcgghh";

if (Value1.Contains("abc"))
{
    found = true;
}
```

It could be within the first 3, 4 or 5 characters.

Comment: Sorry guys I wasn't clear when I first posted, the value abc (this changes) maybe within the first X number of characters. E.g. 3,4,5 etc so StartsWith won't work for me.

Answer (score 56):

Or if you need to set the value of found:

```
found = Value1.StartsWith("abc")
```

Edit: Given your edit, I would do something like:

```
found = Value1.Substring(0, 5).Contains("abc")
```

Comment: Also add a check to see if the Value1 String has a length of 5 before doing this.

Answer (score 19):

I would use one of the of the overloads of the IndexOf method

```
bool found = Value1.IndexOf("abc", 0, 7) != -1;
```

Answer (score 12):

shorter version:

```
found = Value1.StartsWith("abc");
```

sorry, but I am a stickler for 'less' code.

---

Given the edit of the questioner I would actually go with something that accepted an offset, this may in fact be a Great place to an Extension method that overloads StartsWith

```
public static class StackOverflowExtensions
{
    public static bool StartsWith(this String val, string findString, int count)
    {
        return val.Substring(0, count).Contains(findString);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he wanted to match "1abcwhatever" and "xyabcwhatever" as well.

Comment: he changed that after most of us had written an answer

Answer (score 8):

```
if (Value1.StartsWith("abc")) { found = true; }
```

Comment: I don't think that meets the requirements.

Comment: Isn't that the same as found = Value1.StartsWith("abc") ?

Comment: @Will - true but as in all software projects the requirements have been changed since I had a go at it. 

@Jim - True but I kept the style of the author of question.

Answer (score 7):

Use IndexOf is easier and high performance.

```
int index = Value1.IndexOf("abc");
bool found = index >= 0 && index < x;
```

Comment: But less efficient if _Value1_ is a long string and _x_ is small.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need :

```
if (Value1.StartsWith("abc"))
{
found = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're close... but use:
`if (Value1.StartsWith("abc"))`

Answer (score 3):

A more explicit version is

```
found = Value1.StartsWith("abc", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

It's best to always explicitly list the particular comparison you are doing.  The String class can be somewhat inconsistent with the type of comparisons that are used.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use regular expressions (less readable though)

```
string regex = "^.{0,7}abc";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regex);
string Value1 = "sssddabcgghh";

Console.WriteLine(reg.Match(Value1).Success);
```

Comment: This works but the regular expression is inefficient. It will grab the first 7 characters and then test for "abc". If that test fails it will back up one character and try again. This process will continue until either a match is found or the beginning of the string is reached. The non-greedy equivalent is _"^.{0,7}?abc"_.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on from the answer below i have created this method:

```
    public static bool ContainsInvalidStrings(IList<string> invalidStrings,string stringToCheck)
    {

        foreach (string invalidString in invalidStrings)
        {
            var index = stringToCheck.IndexOf(invalidString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

it can be used like this:

```
            var unsupportedTypes = new List<string>()
        {
            "POINT Empty",
            "MULTIPOINT",
            "MULTILINESTRING",
            "MULTIPOLYGON",
            "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION",
            "CIRCULARSTRING",
            "COMPOUNDCURVE",
            "CURVEPOLYGON",
            "MULTICURVE",
            "TRIANGLE",
            "TIN",
            "POLYHEDRALSURFACE"
        };


            bool hasInvalidValues =   ContainsInvalidStrings(unsupportedTypes,possibleWKT);
```

you can check for multiple invalid values this way.