# Comparing char arrays method

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char, string-comparison

I've been playing space engineers which has been epic since they added in-game programming, I'm trying to make a gps auto-pilot navigation script and have to get the block positions finding the blocks by name looking for a smaller string within their bigger string name. I wrote this method to find a small string (word) in a larger string (name of the block):

```
bool contains(string text, string wordInText)
{
    char[] chText = text.ToCharArray();
    char[] chWord = wordInText.ToCharArray();

    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < chText.Length - chWord.Length ; i++)    
        for(int j = 0; j < chWord.Length;j++,index++)
            if (chWord[0] == chText[i])
                index = i;
            else if (chWord[j] == chText[index]){}                
            else if (index == chWord.Length-1)
                return true;
            else break;

    return false; 
}
```

Am I even doing it right, should I be doing it another shorter way?

Comment: Why don't you use String.Substring() methid https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: There's already a .Contains() method for strings

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if string contains specific substring within the first X characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501026/how-to-determine-if-string-contains-specific-substring-within-the-first-x-charac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple with .Contains() which returns a bool.

```
text.Contains(wordInText);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to check if a string contains an other string, then you can use `string.Contains`, the string class already provides a bunch of methods for string operations.

Comment: I think that just returns true if the string is exact and not if the string your looking for is at the end.

Comment: @mattstack No, it returns true if the second string is contained within the first string.  Which is what you specified in the question.  If you want to test if a string ends with something (a specific case of Contains), use EndsWith.

Comment: So it does , not sure what I did wrong the first time around. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the `String` class already has a `Contains` method that should give you what you need.

That said, your code doesn't work.  I can see where you're going with it, but it's just not going to work.  Stepping through it in a proper dev environment would show you why, but since this is more in the way of a script that's probably not an option.

So... the basic idea is to iterate through the string you're searching in, looking for matches against the string your searching.  Your outer `for` statement looks fine for this, but your inner statements are a bit messed up.

Firstly, you're doing the first character check repeatedly.  It's wasteful, and misplaced.  Do it once per iteration of the outer loop.

Second, your exit condition is going to fire when the first character of `wordInText` matches the characters at index `wordInText.Length` in `text` which is not apparently what you want.

In fact you're all tripped up over the `index` variable.  It isn't actually useful, so I'd drop it completely.

Here's a similar piece of code that should work.  It is still much slower than the library `String.Compare` method, but hopefully it shows you how you might achieve the same thing.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= chText.Length - chWord.Length; i++)
{
    if (chText[i] == chWord[0])
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < chWord.Length; j++)
        {
            if (chText[i + j] != chWord[j])
                break;
        }
        if (j == chWord.Length)
            return true;
    }
}
return false;
```