# How to check a text contains a certain character within selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a method below where I retrieve a HTML tag:

```
    public void CheckEmailDisplayed()
    {
        var email = _driver.FindElement(ConfirmationResponsiveElements.ViewEmail);

    }
```

ViewEmail is below:

```
public static By ViewEmail => By.ClassName("confirmation-banner__text");
```

The HTML it corresponds to is:

```
<div class="confirmation-banner__text firefinder-match">
<p>
 We've sent an email to
<strong>firstname@xxx.com</strong>
</p>
<p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is be able to use the variable `email` to check that the text contains an @. This is to help determine an email address is displayed. How can this be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Check for the @ symbol

```
        string email = "test@domain.com";
        if (email.Contains("@"))
        {
            // code here
        }
```

Option 2: Validate Email Address

```
public static bool IsEmail(string emailToValidate)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailToValidate)) return true;

    return Regex.IsMatch(emailToValidate, @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");
}
```

How to use option 2:

```
        string email = "test@domain.com";            
        if (IsEmail(email))
        {
            // valid email address
        }
        else
        {
            // not a valid email address
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another definition

```
public static By ViewEmailAddress => By.TagName("strong");
```

Then use

```
var emailAddress = emai.FindElement(ConfirmationResponsiveElements.ViewEmailAddress);
var emailAddressText = emailAddress.Text;
```

And then you can do different operations that you want on `emailAddressText`. Like validating it having `@` or doing more complex validations like a email pattern check

Answer (score 0):

You can use IndexOf method

```
bool found = Value1.IndexOf("abc", 0, 7) != -1;
```

OR

You can also use regular expressions (less readable though)

```
string regex = "^.{0,7}abc";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regex);
string Value1 = "sssddabcgghh";

Console.WriteLine(reg.Match(Value1).Success);
```

Source :-
[How to determine if string contains specific substring within the first X characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501026/how-to-determine-if-string-contains-specific-substring-within-the-first-x-charac)